# What is the difference between に基づいて and を基に?

Tags: word-choice

このアイデアは君の話**を基に**考えたよ。

歴史的事実**に基づいて**作られた映画。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the kanji 基 is used, ～を基に(して) and ～に基づいて are completely interchangeable. They both mean "based on ～".

Note that もと can be written as 元/本/素, too, and をもとに(して) is not always interchangeable with に基づいて.

- 元手/資金: 1000万円をもとに事業を始める
- 材料/原料: 煮干をもとにスープを作る
- 原因: 些細なことをもとに喧嘩が始まる

Comment: 「下」も「許」も... ご尤もです！